# Style colors of openlayer map: roads, terrain and more

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

i want migrate from google map to openlayer map v5. I need some help for modify the colours or objects of map, example: roads, terrain, water.

the basic code:

```
 <script>
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({center: ol.proj.transform([13.12754,45.68177], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), zoom:12}),
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })],
    target:'map'
});


var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
        src: 'images/marker.png'
    })
  })
});
map.addLayer(markers);      

var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([13.12754,45.68177])));
markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);     

</script>
```

Comment: You cannot change the style of a raster source, although there are many alternatives to OSM each with their own styles.  If you need to specify your own styles use a vector source such as Mapbox, see the example  https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html and the styling used in it https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js

Comment: Hello dear Mike, thank you, but its possible create a own style without mapbox? mapbox you have to pay?

Comment: Mapbox is free up to a monthly limit (50000 views, 4 tiles count as 1 view).  But there are some completely free alternatives available from arcgis https://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=30de8da907d240a0bccd5ad3ff25ef4a&focus=layers&view=list&start=1&num=60#content including Esri `https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf` and one based on OSM `https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf`

Comment: Link to help for styling here https://esri.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c908722b0841404ba6a87d6221f201e4

Comment: yes, i seen the plan, but i think it's same at gogole maps, if user move the map a long you will consume all view so fast. you have some info about mapbox as free with use own server? or do you know OpenMapTiles? thanks

Comment: OpenMapTiles requires a MapTiler API key - the free limit is 100,000 tiles per month.  The ESRI hosted OSM vector tiles require no key and is free CCbyA, but there are no links provided to ready made style scripts for OpenLayers so you may need to do your own setup or search.

Comment: You could create your own tile server as described at https://switch2osm.org/, still, this would imply server costs